# Server Raid Failure and Boot into Grub

Tags: linux, raid

My server failed and and was booting into grub rescue.  Now it is saying it cant even find the OS.  I went into bios and checked the drives, and none of them seem to have failed.  In the system events it says there in an incomplete raid discovered.  Is there a way to go about fixing this or do I just have to deal with my data being lost?

Comment: Lots of information is missing from this question. What RAID level was used? At which layer is this RAID implemented? Is the RAID done in hardware, BIOS, or kernel? What OS is it running? (I am guessing Linux, but grub could be used to boot other operating systems.)

Comment: Sorry about that. It was raid 6. Raid was set up in bios. Yes running Linux 12.04 believe. Sorry for the lack of information I took this over for someone and it died on me.

Comment: There is no such thing as Linux 12.04. You might be thinking of Ubuntu 12.04. RAID 6 is supposed to be able to tolerate the loss of two drives (as long as there are no bad sectors) and the loss of one drive along with lots of bad sectors. So a completely dying RAID 6 is not that likely, if defective drives are replaced quickly after failure. Could it have happened, that this machine was left running with a dead drive that did not get replaced, or has something else been happening to the machine? Could external factors have killed multiple drives simultaneously?

Comment: It was doing fine and then just started beeping continuously. When I checked it out it was getting the errors about the raid not in normal state. I'm a little confused too because from what I see all of the drives are fine

Comment: Where exactly do you see the messages about the incomplete RAID? And clearly it must be loading GRUB from somewhere. But I don't know if that is the same GRUB install it was booting from, when it was working, or if you might have had multiple copies of GRUB installed on different disks.

Comment: Isee the message in bios under system events

Comment: Is there any timestamps attached to those events? Since it is able to load GRUB, and none of the disks are reported as bad, and it is after all RAID 6, it should be possible to recover most of the data. But I don't know enough about the actual RAID you are using to help you much further. If you give some more information about the RAID you are using, maybe somebody who knows it can step in and help.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on this.  I recently I built a new server from parts and pulled the raid controller from this server.  It would not even work on the server so I am under the assumption that the raid controller was faulty.